How to model squishy spheres?
I'm trying to model squishy spheres/ balls, like these:

Like in the two images, I would like to have an object on top of them causing the indent/ squeeze.

I've tried using the sculpt mode and also proportional editing (smooth) but wasn't too happy with the results. I admit I'm new to Blender/ 3D so may be on the wrong path completely OR may have given up too early on the two methods I tried.

I haven't tried it, but this looks like something you could try to achieve with soft-body physics...

Create Sphere. The icosphere is better suited for this task. Subdivide it enough times (at least 6).

Select the area of the shape you need from the top view (for example)

Then with proportional editing enabled "S → Z → 0" (Aligns all points to one plane along the Z axis)

With Proportional Editing still on, shape the dent (experiment with Proportional Editing Radius)

Then apply "Shade Smooth"

And to top it off, smooth the vertices with "Smooth Vertices". Experiment with the strength and number of passes.

Here's what I got:


UPD: I got the best result with sharp proportional editing.
